# nose reports cumulative coverage

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, nose

Image a situation where you have a `BASE_CLASS`. Several class inherits from that class: `CHILD_A`, `CHILD_B`, `CHILD_C`.

Now let us write unit tests, but ONLY for `CHILD_A`, `CHILD_B`, `CHILD_C`. I would suspect, that the coverage for `BASE_CLASS` is 0%. Unfortunately, `nose` takes cumulative coverage, which is not what I want. I tried using the `---cover-erase` flag while executing the tests, but that doesn't help.

My question is: How can I force `nose` not to use cumulative coverage? I need this to know how good is the unit test for `BASE_CLASS`.

Comment: But the tests are running that code. Python doesn't just magically know what code is `BASE_CLASS` because some classes inherit form it, it has to go look at. Therefore those lines are being run during the tests.

Comment: That's what I expected. So no, it's not possible

Comment: Anything is possible if you write the code for it. You just have to determine whether or not the result is worth the effort.

Comment: Yep, We've been doing it the way that if we find some_file_unit_test.py file, then WE KNOW that one folder up there is some_file.py. This way we know that this unit test is for this specific file. We store the coverage from that test and move on. We thought of moving to nose, but because of what you mentioned earlier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests are running the code in `BASE_CLASS`. Python doesn't just know what in the base class when creating sub class instances. It has to go to the base class and look at the code there.

If you want to see how good your coverage for that particular base class you can run the test case/method specific to that class. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests):

```
# Run all the tests in the animals.tests module
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests

# Run all the tests found within the 'animals' package
$ ./manage.py test animals

# Run just one test case
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests.AnimalTestCase

# Run just one test method
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests.AnimalTestCase.test_animals_can_speak
```